# pytorch_geometric 'GlobalStorage' object has no attribute 'edge_indexes'

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, pytorch-geometric

I am working on Unsupervised Domain Adaptation and I'm working on a geometric learning approach to this problem. In this approach the a custom model uses the scores of a CNN model (in my case a pretrained ResNet50) and uses the class scores of the original ImageNet to build a graph and applies a GCN to the resulting graph. Here is the code of my forward pass

```
def forward(self, x):
    
    features = self.cnn.forward(x)
    scores = self.dsa.forward(x)
    transposed_scores = torch.transpose(scores, 0, 1)
    adjacency_matrix = torch.matmul(scores, transposed_scores)
    sparse_adj_matrix = dense_to_sparse(adjacency_matrix)       
    
    edge_index, edge_attr = sparse_adj_matrix[0], sparse_adj_matrix[1]
    graph = geometric_data(scores, edge_index=edge_index)
    graph.to(self.device)

    gcn_features = self.gcn(graph.x, graph.edge_indexes)
    concat_features = torch.cat((features, gcn_features))
    domain_classification = self.domain_alignment(concat_features)
    pseudo_label = self.classifier(concat_features)

    return domain_classification, pseudo_label
```

The problem is that when calling the forward method, I get a runtime error saying `'GlobalStorage' object has no attribute 'edge_indexes'`. I'm working on Google Colab. What did I get wrong?

EDIT:
The full error traceback is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch_geometric/data/storage.py in __getattr__(self, key)
     61         try:
---> 62             return self[key]
     63         except KeyError:
  
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch_geometric/data/storage.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     84     def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
---> 85         return self._mapping[key]
     86 

KeyError: 'edge_indexes'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-32-7436986037c0> in <module>
      7 uda_model.to(device)
      8 
----> 9 summary(uda_model, input_size=(3, 224, 224))

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torchsummary/torchsummary.py in summary(model, input_size, batch_size, device)
     70     # make a forward pass
     71     # print(x.shape)
---> 72     model(*x)
     73 
     74     # remove these hooks

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-31-1c0d271d6797> in forward(self, x)
     43         graph = geometric_data(scores, edge_index=edge_index)
     44 
---> 45         gcn_features = self.gcn(graph.x, graph.edge_indexes)
     46         concat_features = torch.cat((features, gcn_features))
     47         domain_classification = self.domain_alignment(concat_features)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch_geometric/data/data.py in __getattr__(self, key)
    426                 "dataset, remove the 'processed/' directory in the dataset's "
    427                 "root folder and try again.")
--> 428         return getattr(self._store, key)
    429 
    430     def __setattr__(self, key: str, value: Any):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch_geometric/data/storage.py in __getattr__(self, key)
     62             return self[key]
     63         except KeyError:
---> 64             raise AttributeError(
     65                 f"'{self.__class__.__name__}' object has no attribute '{key}'")
     66 

AttributeError: 'GlobalStorage' object has no attribute 'edge_indexes'
```

For a minimum reproducible example:

```
import os
import random

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, random_split

from torchvision import transforms

from torch_geometric import nn as geometric_nn
from torch_geometric.data import Data as geometric_data
from torch_geometric.utils import dense_to_sparse

from torchsummary import summary
```

The code here was divided into different cells in Google Colab, here reported in different code sections

```
def get_transform():
    
    transform = list()
    transform.append(transforms.Resize((256, 256)))
    transform.append(transforms.RandomCrop((224, 224)))
    transform.append(transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5))
    transform.append(transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(0.5))
    transform.append(transforms.GaussianBlur((3, 3)))
    transform.append(transforms.RandomGrayscale(0.5))
    transform.append(transforms.ToTensor())
    transform.append(transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                                           std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]))

    return transforms.Compose(transform)
```

---

```
class GCANDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, source_path, target_path, transform=None):

        self.transform = transform
        self.source_path = source_path
        self.target_path = target_path

        self.file_counter = 0
        self.source_length = 0

        for folder in os.listdir(source_path):
            path = os.path.join(source_path, folder)
            self.file_counter += len(os.listdir(path))
            self.source_length += len(os.listdir(path))

        for folder in os.listdir(target_path):
            path = os.path.join(target_path, folder)
            self.file_counter += len(os.listdir(path))

    def __len__(self):

        return self.file_counter

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        path_to_use = self.source_path
        domain = 0
        if index > self.source_length:
            
            path_to_use = self.target_path
            index -= self.source_length
            domain = 1

        label = ''
        image = 0

        for folder in os.listdir(path_to_use):

            item_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(path_to_use, folder))
            if index - len(item_list) < 0:
                file_to_take = len(item_list) - index - 1
                file_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(path_to_use, folder), item_list[file_to_take])
                image = Image.open(file_path)
                label = folder
        

        if self.transform is not None:

            image = self.transform(image)

        return image, label, domain
```

---

```
class GCANModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes, gcn_in_channels=224, gcn_out_channels=150, device='cuda:0'):
        super(GCANModel, self).__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.cnn = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2)
        features = self.cnn.fc.in_features
        combined_features = features + gcn_out_channels
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(*list(self.cnn.children())[:-1])
        self.dsa = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2)
        self.gcn = geometric_nn.GCNConv(in_channels=gcn_in_channels,
                                        out_channels=gcn_out_channels)

        self.domain_alignment = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=combined_features, out_features=1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=combined_features, out_features=1024),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=num_classes),
            nn.Softmax()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        
        features = self.cnn.forward(x)
        scores = self.dsa.forward(x)
        transposed_scores = torch.transpose(scores, 0, 1)
        adjacency_matrix = torch.matmul(scores, transposed_scores)
        sparse_adj_matrix = dense_to_sparse(adjacency_matrix)       
        
        edge_index, edge_attr = sparse_adj_matrix[0], sparse_adj_matrix[1]
        graph = geometric_data(scores, edge_index=edge_index)
        
        gcn_features = self.gcn(graph.x, graph.edge_indexes)
        concat_features = torch.cat((features, gcn_features))
        domain_classification = self.domain_alignment(concat_features)
        pseudo_label = self.classifier(concat_features)

        return domain_classification, pseudo_label
```

---

```
real_world_path = '/content/Adaptiope/product_images'
products_path = '/content/Adaptiope/real_life'
device='cuda:0'
transform = get_transform()
uda_dataset = GCANDataset(source_path=real_world_path, 
                              target_path=products_path, transform=transform)
    
uda_model = GCANModel(20)
uda_model.to(device)

summary(uda_model, input_size=(3, 224, 224))
```

The dataset is Adaptiope, which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FmdsvetC0oVyrFJ9ER7fcN-cXPOWx2gq/view). The dataset is divided into 3 domains. The synthetic one is ignored, while on the others only 20 classes are considered. The classes mantained are:

backpack, bookcase, car jack, comb, crown, file cabinet, flat iron, game controller, glasses, helicopter, ice skates, letter tray, monitor, mug, network switch, over-ear headphones, pen, purse, stand mixer, stroller

Comment: @kmkurn With this edit I hope you get enough information to help me in some way. My doubt is that with geometric_data I gave to pytorch_geometric the edge_indexes, while the errro says that there is no key edge_indexes

Comment: Is it possible that you meant to access `graph.edge_index` (singular) rather than `graph.edge_indexes`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be edge_index. For a typical torch_geometric dataset for graph, you have x(node features), edge_index(list of node connections, a simpler alternative of adjacency matrix that saves space), y(target), edge_attr(Optional: edge features), batch_index(in case the data has been loaded in the loader to get the batches).